# how to use the pool connection correctly?

Tags: c#, sybase, connection-pooling

i'm developing an application in `C#`, where a "pooling" will be carried out to connect to the database. The database used is `SYBASE`

I currently have the following connection string in my DataAccess `class`

```
using Sybase.Data.AseClient;

public static AseConnection PoolTest () {
    string stringConnection = "Provider = Sybase ASE OLE DB Provider; Data Source = localhost, 5000; Database = Test; Uid = SVJ; Pwd = 123456;" +
                                "Pooling = true;" +
                                "Max Pool Size = 15;" +
                                "Min Pool Size = 1;" + / *
                                "ConnectionReserveTimeout = 3;" + * /
                                "Connection Timeout = 10;" +
                                "Connection Lifetime = 1;" +
                                "ConnectionIdleTimeout = 1;";
                    conn = new AseConnection ();
                    conn.ConnectionString = stringConnection;
}
```

Now, at the moment of calling the instance and generating the connection, they are created without any inconvenience, but after finishing my process, I end my connection with `conn.Close()` and in the database engine when looking at the existing connections, they stay there in a "AWAITING COMMAND" state for an indefinite period and this causes me problems when trying to perform another action in the application since the pool is full, and it is supposed to use the connections that are in status "AWAITING COMMAND"

I understand that if I terminate the connection in my App controller, it closes automatically in the DB engine, if someone can clarify for me if it is normal for this to happen, or if I have any wrongly defined parameters, I thank you in advance .

Comment: Do you put you connection creation in a _using statement_? You shouldn't have any need to call Close and the connection should be released to pool reuse

Comment: I call the connection like this: `conn = DataAccess.PoolTest(); conn.Open();
                comand = new AseCommand("procedure", conn);` and at the end of everything I close the connection with  `conn.Close()`

Comment: That looks like you are storing the connection class. Don't do that. Just create a new one. It will come from the pool. Then use the using syntax everywhere when "creating" new connections. So that you can create connection as late as possible and destroy them as early as possible.  And be aware that creating/destroying means taken a connection from the pool and putting it back into it. Its no real creation/destroying.

Comment: I understand that the `using` command works the same as this but without specifying `conn.close()`

Comment: It should be _using (ASEConnection conn = DataAccess.....){   code here that use the connection }_ at brace exit the connection is released to the pool. Do not use global variables for connections.

Comment: No, your code lacks the call to Dispose and we don't know for sure if it is called from inside the Close. Moreover, what if you have an exception? using statement will dispose correctly also in case of exceptions

Comment: good. I'll try to change the syntax and let you know if it works.

Comment: seems to be working smoothly when using the `using` statement, thanks for the help